# Apply different styles using GS pointstacker's "count" variable

Tags: geoserver, point, sld, svg

In an effort to give the Geoserver’s pointstacker method more life, I only applied it to scales greater than 1: 34085, so that on the lower scales it is possible to use “getfeature” function in the click event of the mouse, by a plain style.

Still, I'd like Geoserver to categorize the size of the SVG icon I'm using, according to the numerical value of the "count" variable used in the transform function.

A - The image with the expected behavior:

[image]

B - The Code's Draft image for this logic implement:

[image]

C -  Code used in this attempt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
 xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld"
 xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>Pontos Empilhados 2</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Title>Pontos Empilhados 2</Title>
      <Abstract>Teste 2 de pontos empilhados</Abstract>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Transformation>
          <ogc:Function name="vec:PointStacker">
            <ogc:Function name="parameter">
              <ogc:Literal>data</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:Function>
            <ogc:Function name="parameter">
              <ogc:Literal>cellSize</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>100</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:Function>
            <ogc:Function name="parameter">
              <ogc:Literal>outputBBOX</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Function name="env">
                <ogc:Literal>wms_bbox</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:Function>
            </ogc:Function>
            <ogc:Function name="parameter">
              <ogc:Literal>outputWidth</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Function name="env">
                <ogc:Literal>wms_width</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:Function>
            </ogc:Function>
            <ogc:Function name="parameter">
              <ogc:Literal>outputHeight</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Function name="env">
                <ogc:Literal>wms_height</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:Function>
            </ogc:Function>
          </ogc:Function>
        </Transformation>
         <Rule>
          <Name>Escala 34085 ou superior</Name>
            <MinScaleDenominator>34085</MinScaleDenominator>
              <Rule>
                <Name>Count entre 2 e 10</Name>
                  <ogc:Filter>
                    <ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
                    <ogc:PropertyName>count</ogc:PropertyName>
                    <ogc:LowerBoundary>
                    <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
                    </ogc:LowerBoundary>
                    <ogc:UpperBoundary>
                    <ogc:Literal>10</ogc:Literal>
                    </ogc:UpperBoundary>
                    </ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
                  </ogc:Filter>
                <PointSymbolizer>
                 <Graphic>
                  <ExternalGraphic>
                  <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="v2.0_pontos.svg" />
                  <Format>image/svg+xml</Format>
                  </ExternalGraphic>
                  <Size>
                  <ogc:Literal>20</ogc:Literal>
                  </Size>
                 </Graphic>
               </PointSymbolizer>
                 <TextSymbolizer>
                  <Label>
                   <ogc:PropertyName>count</ogc:PropertyName>
                  </Label>
                  <Font>
                   <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
                   <CssParameter name="font-size">12</CssParameter>
                   <CssParameter name="font-weight">bold</CssParameter>
                  </Font>
                  <LabelPlacement>
                   <PointPlacement>
                    <AnchorPoint>
                    <AnchorPointX>0.0</AnchorPointX>
                    <AnchorPointY>0.0</AnchorPointY>
                    </AnchorPoint>
                   </PointPlacement>
                  </LabelPlacement>
                  <Halo>
                   <Radius>2</Radius>
                   <Fill>
                    <CssParameter name="fill">#ffffff</CssParameter>
                   </Fill>
                  </Halo>
                  <Fill>
                   <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
                  </Fill>
                 </TextSymbolizer>
               </Rule>

               <Rule>
                <Name>Count entre 11 e 50</Name>
                  <ogc:Filter>
                    <ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
                    <ogc:PropertyName>count</ogc:PropertyName>
                    <ogc:LowerBoundary>
                    <ogc:Literal>11</ogc:Literal>
                    </ogc:LowerBoundary>
                    <ogc:UpperBoundary>
                    <ogc:Literal>50</ogc:Literal>
                    </ogc:UpperBoundary>
                    </ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
                  </ogc:Filter>
                <PointSymbolizer>
                 <Graphic>
                  <ExternalGraphic>
                  <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="v2.0_pontos.svg" />
                  <Format>image/svg+xml</Format>
                  </ExternalGraphic>
                  <Size>
                  <ogc:Literal>30</ogc:Literal>
                  </Size>
                 </Graphic>
               </PointSymbolizer>
                 <TextSymbolizer>
                  <Label>
                   <ogc:PropertyName>count</ogc:PropertyName>
                  </Label>
                  <Font>
                   <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
                   <CssParameter name="font-size">12</CssParameter>
                   <CssParameter name="font-weight">bold</CssParameter>
                  </Font>
                  <LabelPlacement>
                   <PointPlacement>
                    <AnchorPoint>
                    <AnchorPointX>0.0</AnchorPointX>
                    <AnchorPointY>0.0</AnchorPointY>
                    </AnchorPoint>
                   </PointPlacement>
                  </LabelPlacement>
                  <Halo>
                   <Radius>2</Radius>
                   <Fill>
                    <CssParameter name="fill">#ffffff</CssParameter>
                   </Fill>
                  </Halo>
                  <Fill>
                   <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
                  </Fill>
                 </TextSymbolizer>
               </Rule>           

               <Rule>
                <Name>Count entre 51 e 100</Name>
                  <ogc:Filter>
                    <ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
                    <ogc:PropertyName>count</ogc:PropertyName>
                    <ogc:LowerBoundary>
                    <ogc:Literal>51</ogc:Literal>
                    </ogc:LowerBoundary>
                    <ogc:UpperBoundary>
                    <ogc:Literal>100</ogc:Literal>
                    </ogc:UpperBoundary>
                    </ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
                  </ogc:Filter>
                <PointSymbolizer>
                 <Graphic>
                  <ExternalGraphic>
                  <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="v2.0_pontos.svg" />
                  <Format>image/svg+xml</Format>
                  </ExternalGraphic>
                  <Size>
                  <ogc:Literal>40</ogc:Literal>
                  </Size>
                 </Graphic>
               </PointSymbolizer>
                 <TextSymbolizer>
                  <Label>
                   <ogc:PropertyName>count</ogc:PropertyName>
                  </Label>
                  <Font>
                   <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
                   <CssParameter name="font-size">12</CssParameter>
                   <CssParameter name="font-weight">bold</CssParameter>
                  </Font>
                  <LabelPlacement>
                   <PointPlacement>
                    <AnchorPoint>
                    <AnchorPointX>0.0</AnchorPointX>
                    <AnchorPointY>0.0</AnchorPointY>
                    </AnchorPoint>
                   </PointPlacement>
                  </LabelPlacement>
                  <Halo>
                   <Radius>2</Radius>
                   <Fill>
                    <CssParameter name="fill">#ffffff</CssParameter>
                   </Fill>
                  </Halo>
                  <Fill>
                   <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
                  </Fill>
                 </TextSymbolizer>
               </Rule>           

               <Rule>
                <Name>Count entre 101 e 200</Name>
                  <ogc:Filter>
                    <ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
                    <ogc:PropertyName>count</ogc:PropertyName>
                    <ogc:LowerBoundary>
                    <ogc:Literal>101</ogc:Literal>
                    </ogc:LowerBoundary>
                    <ogc:UpperBoundary>
                    <ogc:Literal>200</ogc:Literal>
                    </ogc:UpperBoundary>
                    </ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
                  </ogc:Filter>
                <PointSymbolizer>
                 <Graphic>
                  <ExternalGraphic>
                  <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="v2.0_pontos.svg" />
                  <Format>image/svg+xml</Format>
                  </ExternalGraphic>
                  <Size>
                  <ogc:Literal>50</ogc:Literal>
                  </Size>
                 </Graphic>
               </PointSymbolizer>
                 <TextSymbolizer>
                  <Label>
                   <ogc:PropertyName>count</ogc:PropertyName>
                  </Label>
                  <Font>
                   <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
                   <CssParameter name="font-size">12</CssParameter>
                   <CssParameter name="font-weight">bold</CssParameter>
                  </Font>
                  <LabelPlacement>
                   <PointPlacement>
                    <AnchorPoint>
                    <AnchorPointX>0.0</AnchorPointX>
                    <AnchorPointY>0.0</AnchorPointY>
                    </AnchorPoint>
                   </PointPlacement>
                  </LabelPlacement>
                  <Halo>
                   <Radius>2</Radius>
                   <Fill>
                    <CssParameter name="fill">#ffffff</CssParameter>
                   </Fill>
                  </Halo>
                  <Fill>
                   <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
                  </Fill>
                 </TextSymbolizer>
               </Rule>           

               <Rule>
                <Name>Count entre 201 e 999</Name>
                  <ogc:Filter>
                    <ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
                    <ogc:PropertyName>count</ogc:PropertyName>
                    <ogc:LowerBoundary>
                    <ogc:Literal>201</ogc:Literal>
                    </ogc:LowerBoundary>
                    <ogc:UpperBoundary>
                    <ogc:Literal>999</ogc:Literal>
                    </ogc:UpperBoundary>
                    </ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
                  </ogc:Filter>
                <PointSymbolizer>
                 <Graphic>
                  <ExternalGraphic>
                  <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="v2.0_pontos.svg" />
                  <Format>image/svg+xml</Format>
                  </ExternalGraphic>
                  <Size>
                  <ogc:Literal>60</ogc:Literal>
                  </Size>
                 </Graphic>
               </PointSymbolizer>
                 <TextSymbolizer>
                  <Label>
                   <ogc:PropertyName>count</ogc:PropertyName>
                  </Label>
                  <Font>
                   <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
                   <CssParameter name="font-size">12</CssParameter>
                   <CssParameter name="font-weight">bold</CssParameter>
                  </Font>
                  <LabelPlacement>
                   <PointPlacement>
                    <AnchorPoint>
                    <AnchorPointX>0.0</AnchorPointX>
                    <AnchorPointY>0.0</AnchorPointY>
                    </AnchorPoint>
                   </PointPlacement>
                  </LabelPlacement>
                  <Halo>
                   <Radius>2</Radius>
                   <Fill>
                    <CssParameter name="fill">#ffffff</CssParameter>
                   </Fill>
                  </Halo>
                  <Fill>
                   <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
                  </Fill>
                 </TextSymbolizer>
               </Rule>           
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: I'm sorry if it was not clear enough, but I'm wanting the SVG icons to have the size depending on the value of the "count" variable of the pointstacker method

Comment: Does the example here work for you http://suite.opengeo.org/docs/latest/cartography/rt/pointstacker.html?

Comment: @user30184, I've built the above code with the logic taken from your URL example, but it didn't worked out as I planned.

Comment: Try to analyze what makes the difference. Is that in using SVG? What if you do exactly as in the tutorial?

Comment: It is not working... how? Can you share the resulting map?

Comment: @user30184 and Andrea, the code and logic from the example cited page do work to put svg icons on different sizes, deppending on the "count" value, but when I try to simbolize it only for scales higher than 1:34085 (through <MinScaleDenominator>34085</MinScaleDenominator> parameter), It doesn't work anymore... Just to refresh, I'm trying to pointstack the point layer for higher scales and plain style for lower scales (so the user can click and get feature information, but only on lower scales than 1:34085).

Comment: I really recommend to tell that information in the very beginning of your question. If everthing works without MinScaleDenominator it would be polite to emphasize it.

Comment: This question is compounded: one is to stylize SVG symbols in different sizes depending on the value of the "count" variable and the other is to apply the method only after the 1: 34.085 scale ... what do you suggest? Finish this post (SVG icons in different sizes) as solved and open another new one to apply pointstacker method depending on the zoom level? Thanks

Comment: Renan you should really rework your question.... right now it reads like "here is the logic, here is how it should like, here is the style... figure the everything else by yourself!".

Comment: Hope my answer is clear enough and that I didn't messed up the Forum's policy. Thanks everyone that always comment or clarify.

Comment: @Renan Menelli your answer is perfect for me. but How did you use the GetFeatureInfo method? I edited my style file according to your answer. But when I use GetFeatureInfo, it returns results such as count, countunique in properties as the main output.
How can I retrieve my data in the table when I get information from the relevant point?[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7haO8.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7haO8.png)

Comment: Hello, forgive me for saying this, but my part in this project was in the front-end style, organizing the spatial information, styling it (SLD) and developing the icons (SVG). 

The back-end part was developed by someone else, where I remember that the Leaflet.js library was used to search for information in Geoserver, which in turn integrates with a PostGIS database. 

Unfortunately I no longer have contact with this backend programmer to ask your question. 

That project was eventually replaced by another spatial data demonstration system.

Anything else you need, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer is based on what I've found out and the final code is at the end:

**1 -** To render SVG icon's size depending on *"count"* value, I've used the SLD example code that **@user30184** mentioned ([here](http://suite.opengeo.org/docs/latest/cartography/rt/pointstacker.html#sld)), contextualizing it to my project;

**2 -** Geoserver doesn't allow to insert a rule inside another rule: I was trying to build one rule for the scale and several *"sub-rules"* for different *"count"* values and consequently, different SVG icon size - **THIS CODE DOES NOT WORK**;

```
 (...)  </Transformation>
         <Rule>
            <MinScaleDenominator>34085</MinScaleDenominator>
             <Rule>
              <ogc:Filter>
                <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
                  <ogc:PropertyName>count</ogc:PropertyName>
                  <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
              </ogc:Filter>
          <PointSymbolizer> (...)
```

**3 -** With that in mind, I rebuilt the conditional structure code, repeating the scale parameter inside each *"svg icon size rule"*:

```
(...)  </Transformation>
        <Rule>
         <Name>Regra 1</Name>
         <MinScaleDenominator>34085</MinScaleDenominator>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>count</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <PointSymbolizer>
          <Graphic>
           <ExternalGraphic>
            <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="v1.1_pontos.svg" />
            <Format>image/svg</Format>
           </ExternalGraphic>
           <Size>
            <ogc:Literal>20</ogc:Literal>
           </Size>
          </Graphic>
          </PointSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
        <Rule>
         <Name>Regra 2</Name>
         <MinScaleDenominator>34085</MinScaleDenominator>
          <ogc:Filter>
           <ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
            <ogc:PropertyName>count</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:LowerBoundary>
             <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:LowerBoundary>
            <ogc:UpperBoundary>
             <ogc:Literal>10</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:UpperBoundary>
           </ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <PointSymbolizer>   (...)
```

**4 -** At the end, this is the map result, as I expected:

**A -** Zoom level 1 - Scale 1:5000 meters (as pointstacker method):

[image]

**B -** Zoom level 2 - Scale 1:2000 meters (as pointstacker method):

[image]

**C -** Zoom level 3 - Scale 1:1000 meters (as pointstacker method):

[image]

**D -** Zoom level 4 to 9 - Scale 1:500 meters and lowers (as plain SVG style and with *"getfeatureinfo"* working whenever user's click mouse event occur):

[image]

**5 - FINAL FULL WORKING SLD CODE:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
  xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>teste_III_pointstacker</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Title>teste III</Title>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Transformation>
          <ogc:Function name="vec:PointStacker">
            <ogc:Function name="parameter">
              <ogc:Literal>data</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:Function>
            <ogc:Function name="parameter">
              <ogc:Literal>cellSize</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>60</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:Function>
            <ogc:Function name="parameter">
              <ogc:Literal>outputBBOX</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Function name="env">
              <ogc:Literal>wms_bbox</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:Function>
            </ogc:Function>
            <ogc:Function name="parameter">
              <ogc:Literal>outputWidth</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Function name="env">
              <ogc:Literal>wms_width</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:Function>
            </ogc:Function>
            <ogc:Function name="parameter">
              <ogc:Literal>outputHeight</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Function name="env">
              <ogc:Literal>wms_height</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:Function>
            </ogc:Function>
          </ogc:Function>
        </Transformation>
        <Rule>
         <Name>Regra 1</Name>
         <MinScaleDenominator>34085</MinScaleDenominator>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>count</ogc:PropertyName>
             <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <PointSymbolizer>
         <Graphic>
          <ExternalGraphic>
           <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="v1.1_pontos.svg" />
           <Format>image/svg</Format>
         </ExternalGraphic>
         <Size>
         <ogc:Literal>20</ogc:Literal>
         </Size>
       </Graphic>
      </PointSymbolizer>
     </Rule>
     <Rule>
      <Name>Regra 2</Name>
      <MinScaleDenominator>34085</MinScaleDenominator>
        <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
              <ogc:PropertyName>count</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:LowerBoundary>
                <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:LowerBoundary>
              <ogc:UpperBoundary>
                <ogc:Literal>10</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:UpperBoundary>
            </ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
          </ogc:Filter>
                <PointSymbolizer>
                 <Graphic>
                  <ExternalGraphic>
                  <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="v2.1_pontos.svg" />
                  <Format>image/svg+xml</Format>
                  </ExternalGraphic>
                  <Size>
                  <ogc:Literal>30</ogc:Literal>
                  </Size>
                 </Graphic>
               </PointSymbolizer>
          <TextSymbolizer>
            <Label>
              <ogc:PropertyName>count</ogc:PropertyName>
            </Label>
            <Font>
              <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-size">8</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-weight">bold</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-style">italic</CssParameter>
            </Font>
            <LabelPlacement>
              <PointPlacement>
              <AnchorPoint>
                <AnchorPointX>0.5</AnchorPointX>
                <AnchorPointY>0.8</AnchorPointY>
              </AnchorPoint>
              </PointPlacement>
            </LabelPlacement>
            <Halo>
              <Radius>2</Radius>
              <Fill>
                <CssParameter name="fill">#ffffff</CssParameter>
                <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">1.0</CssParameter>
              </Fill>
            </Halo>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">1.0</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
          </TextSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
        <Rule>
         <Name>Regra 3</Name>
         <MinScaleDenominator>34085</MinScaleDenominator>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
              <ogc:PropertyName>count</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:LowerBoundary>
                <ogc:Literal>11</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:LowerBoundary>
              <ogc:UpperBoundary>
                <ogc:Literal>50</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:UpperBoundary>
            </ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
          </ogc:Filter>
                <PointSymbolizer>
                 <Graphic>
                  <ExternalGraphic>
                  <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="v2.1_pontos.svg" />
                  <Format>image/svg+xml</Format>
                  </ExternalGraphic>
                  <Size>
                  <ogc:Literal>40</ogc:Literal>
                  </Size>
                 </Graphic>
               </PointSymbolizer>
          <TextSymbolizer>
            <Label>
              <ogc:PropertyName>count</ogc:PropertyName>
            </Label>
            <Font>
              <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-size">10</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-weight">bold</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-style">italic</CssParameter>
            </Font>
            <LabelPlacement>
              <PointPlacement>
              <AnchorPoint>
                <AnchorPointX>0.5</AnchorPointX>
                <AnchorPointY>0.8</AnchorPointY>
              </AnchorPoint>
              </PointPlacement>
            </LabelPlacement>
            <Halo>
              <Radius>2</Radius>
              <Fill>
                <CssParameter name="fill">#ffffff</CssParameter>
                <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">1.0</CssParameter>
              </Fill>
            </Halo>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">1.0</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
          </TextSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
        <Rule>
         <Name>Regra 4</Name>
         <MinScaleDenominator>34085</MinScaleDenominator>
           <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
              <ogc:PropertyName>count</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:LowerBoundary>
                <ogc:Literal>51</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:LowerBoundary>
              <ogc:UpperBoundary>
                <ogc:Literal>100</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:UpperBoundary>
            </ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
          </ogc:Filter>
                <PointSymbolizer>
                 <Graphic>
                  <ExternalGraphic>
                  <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="v2.1_pontos.svg" />
                  <Format>image/svg+xml</Format>
                  </ExternalGraphic>
                  <Size>
                  <ogc:Literal>50</ogc:Literal>
                  </Size>
                 </Graphic>
               </PointSymbolizer>
          <TextSymbolizer>
            <Label>
              <ogc:PropertyName>count</ogc:PropertyName>
            </Label>
            <Font>
              <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-size">12</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-weight">bold</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-style">italic</CssParameter>
            </Font>
            <LabelPlacement>
              <PointPlacement>
              <AnchorPoint>
                <AnchorPointX>0.5</AnchorPointX>
                <AnchorPointY>0.8</AnchorPointY>
              </AnchorPoint>
              </PointPlacement>
            </LabelPlacement>
            <Halo>
              <Radius>2</Radius>
              <Fill>
                <CssParameter name="fill">#ffffff</CssParameter>
                <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">1.0</CssParameter>
              </Fill>
            </Halo>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">1.0</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
          </TextSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
        <Rule>
         <Name>Regra 5</Name>
         <MinScaleDenominator>34085</MinScaleDenominator>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
              <ogc:PropertyName>count</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:LowerBoundary>
                <ogc:Literal>101</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:LowerBoundary>
              <ogc:UpperBoundary>
                <ogc:Literal>200</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:UpperBoundary>
            </ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
          </ogc:Filter>
                <PointSymbolizer>
                 <Graphic>
                  <ExternalGraphic>
                  <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="v2.1_pontos.svg" />
                  <Format>image/svg+xml</Format>
                  </ExternalGraphic>
                  <Size>
                  <ogc:Literal>60</ogc:Literal>
                  </Size>
                 </Graphic>
               </PointSymbolizer>
          <TextSymbolizer>
            <Label>
              <ogc:PropertyName>count</ogc:PropertyName>
            </Label>
            <Font>
              <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-size">14</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-weight">bold</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-style">italic</CssParameter>
            </Font>
            <LabelPlacement>
              <PointPlacement>
              <AnchorPoint>
                <AnchorPointX>0.5</AnchorPointX>
                <AnchorPointY>0.8</AnchorPointY>
              </AnchorPoint>
              </PointPlacement>
            </LabelPlacement>
            <Halo>
              <Radius>2</Radius>
              <Fill>
                <CssParameter name="fill">#ffffff</CssParameter>
                <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">1.0</CssParameter>
              </Fill>
            </Halo>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">1.0</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
          </TextSymbolizer>
         </Rule>
         <Rule>
          <Name>Regra 6</Name>
          <MinScaleDenominator>34085</MinScaleDenominator>
           <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>count</ogc:PropertyName>
             <ogc:Literal>201</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <PointSymbolizer>
         <Graphic>
          <ExternalGraphic>
           <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="v2.1_pontos.svg" />
           <Format>image/svg</Format>
         </ExternalGraphic>
         <Size>
         <ogc:Literal>70</ogc:Literal>
         </Size>
       </Graphic>
      </PointSymbolizer>
          <TextSymbolizer>
            <Label>
              <ogc:PropertyName>count</ogc:PropertyName>
            </Label>
            <Font>
              <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-size">16</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-weight">bold</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-style">italic</CssParameter>
            </Font>
            <LabelPlacement>
              <PointPlacement>
              <AnchorPoint>
                <AnchorPointX>0.5</AnchorPointX>
                <AnchorPointY>0.8</AnchorPointY>
              </AnchorPoint>
              </PointPlacement>
            </LabelPlacement>
            <Halo>
              <Radius>2</Radius>
              <Fill>
                <CssParameter name="fill">#ffffff</CssParameter>
                <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">1.0</CssParameter>
              </Fill>
            </Halo>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">1.0</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
          </TextSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```